# SQL query for incrementing values of row data through sequencing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have row and column locations of several students.
Assuming number of rows and columns are fixed (to 3x3), how can I have a query result listing all row and column combinations, with students mapped to the correct location?

For example given these students data:

```
Student  Row     Column
Paul     1       1
Chris    1       3
James    2       2
Dwayne   3       3
```

How to have a query output like this:

```
Student  Row  Column
Paul     1       1
NULL     1       2
Chris    1       3
NULL     2       1
James    2       2
NULL     2       3
NULL     3       1
NULL     3       2
Dwayne   3       3
```

Please help! Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34248574/sql-add-rows-depending-on-the-incremental-value-of-a-given-digit-in-a-column

Comment: Please explain your output

Comment: Can you please add table schema, I didn't finished to understand what you want, where is the relation between row and colum columns with oyu expecting output... .

Comment: @Muhammad Muazzam The output shows that the column header is incrementing until it reaches 3 then the row header increments to 2 and so on depending on the current table.

Comment: @Juan Ruiz de Castilla The column header must increment until it reaches 3 then the row header will now increment and so on. I just want to add rows that have a row and column header values even if the student column contains empty fields.

Comment: when you say, the column header must increment, you talk about column header description??, why for example paul, when have value of 1 in row column and value of 1 in column column, have 1 and 2 in the next row?, and Dwayne only have 1 row... .

Comment: @Juan Ruiz de Castilla In the case of student paul, it should only have a value of 1 in both row and column columns but on the next row, it is separated. I just want to have an empty student name but the column and header data must have its incremented value. Thank you Sir.

Comment: @Raven, take a look to my answer, like your update, if you need put off isnull function, do it ;).

Answer (score 1):

While using PHP, Try `mysql_insert_id()` for your Code.

See Example here:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to know that Mysql haven't a implicit generator of N numbers of rows, like other RDBMS have, but you can emulate this using something like this:

http://use-the-index-luke.com/blog/2011-07-30/mysql-row-generator#mysql_generator_code

Take a look for study porpuse.

But for a first approach to resolve your problem, you can try this:

```
SELECT IFNULL((SELECT STUDENT FROM StudentSeatPlan B WHERE B.ROW =  TB.ROW_ AND B.COLUMN = TB.COLUMN_),'') AS STUDENT,
TB.ROW_,TB.COLUMN_
FROM (
SELECT 1 ROW_,1 COLUMN_ UNION ALL 
SELECT 1,2  UNION ALL 
SELECT 1,3  UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,1  UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,2  UNION ALL 
SELECT 2,3  UNION ALL
SELECT 3,1  UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,2  UNION ALL 
SELECT 3,3) TB
```

Whatever, it seems like you have a schema problem, something wrong it happens that you need  generate data in this form in Mysql, maybe you prefered make it in your app if is the case.